# How to get the selected name,value from WPFAutoComplete:TextBoxAutoCompleteProvider event?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am new to XAML forms. I have some code written years ago by another programmer which I now need to modify.   I am trying to intercept the selection that is applied to the textbox when the user presses enter or clicks the mouse on a selection from the dropdown list.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtVendor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="24,299,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
<WPFAutoComplete:TextBoxAutoCompleteProvider x:Name="txtVendorAuto" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="VendorNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="24,322,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" TargetControl="{Binding ElementName=txtVendor}" MaxResults="20" MinWidth="250" MinTypedCharacters="2"/>
```

I thought it would be similar to C#/Vb code in that I would check the selected index change event and get the values, however the only event that looks close is the "SelectionChanged" which fires with any text input and not the actual selected item.   I managed to check for the keydown event in the textbox and look for the enter key and that seems to work, but I cannot determine when someone has selected something via the mouse.  I have checked the various mouse events (left mouse button down,up, etc.)

Is there a way to simply get the item from the search when it is selected (keyboard or mouse)?

Comment: The `TextBox` has a `TextChanged` event which fires whenever the `Text` property is set. Where did you get the `TextBoxAutoCompleteProvider` control from? It's not a built-in control but a custom one.

Comment: The "TextBoxAutoCompleteProvider" is part of an WPFAutoComplete.dll library that was added to the project when it was made. I've tried looking up examples but haven't had much luck.  The "TextChanged" event for the text box fires with any typed character.

Comment: Yes. So what exactly do you need?

Comment: Maybe you should consider posting the implementation of `TextBoxAutoCompleteProvider`.